# Finding polynomials question (combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics

I have two generating series $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ such that $g_n=f_n+a_1f_{n-1}+\cdots+a_nf_{n-k}$ when n>=k are the coefficients of $G(x)$ and $f_n$ are the coefficients of $F(x)$. I need to find two polynomials (finite number of terms) s.t. $a(x)F(x)=G(x)+b(x)$. I keep getting infinite terms for $a(x)$ or $b(x)$. How should I approach this question? So far I have just tried to expand out both sides and compare and I have tried manipulation to equation to be proved.

Comment: Would you latex your question.....

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the Euclidean (long) division of polynomials which should give $G=Fa+b$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division

Comment: That doesn't really help too much. I got a(x) as a series and b(x)=0 but I need two finite polynomials which is why I think my approach may be wrong.

Comment: question edited i made a typo.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve your problem you should need some additional informations, e.g. you need to define the sequences $\{f_n \}$ and $\{g_n\}$ for $n<k$.

Consider the recurrence relation given by 
$$ g_n=f_n+a_1f_{n-1}+ \ldots +a_kf_{n-k},$$
for $n\geq k$. Now multiply both sides for $x^n$ and then sum up to all $n\geq k$,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq k}g_nx^n &=\sum_{n\geq k}f_nx^n +a_1\sum_{n\geq k}f_{n-1}x^n+\ldots + a_k\sum_{n\geq k}f_{n-k}x^n \\
       &=\sum_{n\geq k}f_nx^n+a_1x\sum_{n\geq k}f_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots + a_kx^k\sum_{n\geq k}f_{n-k}x^{n-k} \\
      &=\sum_{n\geq k}f_nx^n+a_1x\sum_{n\geq k-1}f_{n}x^{n}+\ldots + a_kx^k\sum_{n\geq 0}f_{n}x^{n}.
\end{align*}
Now observe that 
$$\sum_{n\geq k}g_nx^n = G(x) -\left(g_0 + g_1x + \ldots +g_{k-1}x^{k-1}\right). $$
For 
$$ \sum_{n\geq k}f_nx^n+a_1x\sum_{n\geq k-1}f_{n}x^{n}+\ldots + a_kx^k\sum_{n\geq 0}f_{n}x^{n},$$
we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq k}f_nx^n &=  F(x) -\left(f_0 + f_1x + \ldots +f_{k-1}x^{k-1}\right)\\
a_1x\sum_{n\geq k-1}f_{n}x^{n} &=a_1x\left(F(x)-\left(f_0 + f_1x + \ldots +f_{k-2}x^{k-2}\right)\right) \\
 \vdots & \\
a_{k-1}x^{k-1} \sum_{n\geq 1}f_{n}x^{n} &=a_{k-1}x^{k-1}\left(F(x)-f_0\right)
\\
a_kx^k\sum_{n\geq 0}f_{n}x^{n} &=a_kx^kF(x).
\end{align*}
Summing up all these equations we obtain
$$ \sum_{n\geq k}f_nx^n+a_1x\sum_{n\geq k-1}f_{n}x^{n}+\ldots + a_kx^k\sum_{n\geq 0}f_{n}x^{n}=a(x)F(x) - h(x),$$
with
\begin{align*}
a(x)& = a_0+a_1x+ \ldots +a_kx^k, \\
h(x)& = h_0+ h_1x+ \ldots+ h_{k-1}x^{k-1},
\end{align*}
where the coefficients of $h$ are given by
$$h_i= \sum_{j=0}^ia_jf_{i-j}.$$
So we obtained the polynomial $a(x)$.
If we call 
$$r(x)=g_0 + g_1x + \ldots +g_{k-1}x^{k-1},$$
we can rewrite
$$ G(x)-r(x)=a(x)F(x)-h(x).$$
Hence 
$$b(x)=h(x)-r(x)$$
is the second polynomial that you were looking for.